# How can one figure out where a particular visual flow is being initiated in an Org?

Tags: visual-workflow

We have come across a visual flow that is sitting in our Org and is activated. I would like to search where it is being used and delete it if is not being used.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to guarantee it's not being used, because it can be referenced in ways that make it very hard to find definitively. For example, a developer might have embedded it in a page using the /flow/flowname URL, constructed the name dynamically and put it in an flow:interview element, etc.

I'd recommend simply deactivating the current version for some period of time (say, 30 days), and if nobody complains that something broke, then delete it, because it most likely wasn't being used. It'd be very hard to prove that it is definitely not being used otherwise.

In the future, I'd recommend including a flow's use in the Description box so that you can determine usage easier in the future. Without proper documentation, it becomes very hard to determine if a particular *anything* is being used without quite a bit of effort.

Comment: @Neema. one could, I suppose, amend the flow to log to a custom object the running user and date/time and target object Id (if any) (or create a Task under the target object and query for that later)- this would give a clue as to who was using it if one wanted to avoid the 'deactivate and wait for scream' approach.

Comment: What I always tell developers or admins working for me if I am reviewing the components they have built is no Description fields filled out or comments line, then this would be classed as failing, no matter how well it fulfils the functional requirement

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of how to find out where it's being called from. You can deactivate it and see who calls. Not the 'best practice', I know, but this way you can just leave as deactivated for, at least a quarter.  It doesn't hurt to have deactivated info, but it does hurt when you delete something and then later find out that a department used it only at quarter end.